# will there be a jsMath-like library or plugins in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am interested to develop a mathematics web forum. I have tried jsMath; it is a cool javascript library to render latex command on the client side.
The rendered output is also beautiful because it can load tex font installed on the client computer.

However, I am wondering its security so I prefer to use jQuery library if this kind of feature is also available.

Is there a plan to develop a library like jsMath in jQuery?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Develop it yourself. Why are you worried about security issues in jsMath? jQuery won't prevent those.

Comment: It's all JavaScript, what do you want the integration with jQuery to provide?

Comment: @the_drow and @Douglas,

I am just considering the maintenance with more innovations in performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use both [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com/) and [jsMath](http://www.math.union.edu/~dpvc/jsMath/) in the same page/application.  I don't see a need to reinvent jsMath as an extension of jQuery.

What security issues do you expect to come up with jsMath?  With any javascript library there's the potential of security issues, but it depends greatly on your implementation.